# PHP/Mysql offset error

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a simple blog in php and getting this error -

> Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple\index.php on line 28 and 29

```
  <?php
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    if ( ! category_exists('name', $post ['name'] ) )  {   //line 28
                $post['name'] = 'Uncategorised';   
                }
                ?>
```

I know the string offset questions have been asked here a lot but still I could not figure out how to fix this one. Please help.

Here is the function category_exists

```
 function category_exists($field,$value)
 {
  $field=mysql_real_escape_string($field);  
  $value=mysql_real_escape_string($value);  

  $query=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM categories WHERE {$field}= '{$value}'");
   echo mysql_error();

    return (mysql_result($query,0)=='0')? false : true;


   }
```

This part of code hopefully will help you understand the `$posts` variable:

```
$posts=get_posts();

  function get_posts($id=null,$cat_id=null){
   $posts=array();
   $query=mysql_query("SELECT posts.id AS post_id, categories.id AS      category_id, title, contents, date_posted, categories.name FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = posts.cat_id ORDER BY post_id DESC");
   while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
   {
   $posts=$row; 
   }
   return $posts;
   }
```

I have the following attributes of posts table -
id,title,cat_id,contents,date_posted.
For the categories table:
id and name.

Comment: show the full code. according to yours $posts is undefined and u should at first get another error like 'invalid ..somt.. for foreach'

Comment: It looks like there is a space between $post and  ['name'], could that be causing issues?

Comment: its not solve your problem. but you certainly shoult replace `$posts=$row;` whith `$posts[]=$row;` in last code-block

Comment: @M0rtiis Thanks man it worked

Answer (score 2):

Your variable $post probably is not an array. Try this first:

```
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    var_dump($post);
}
```

If you see that it is an array, great! Use it as an array. It is very likely that $post will be a string. Therefore when you try to use $post['name'], PHP tells you that 'name' is not an offset for $post string.  Had you used $post[0], that'd give you the first character and 0 would be legal offset...but 'name' wouldn't be a legal offset.

Comment: I tried your way and It's giving me this output -string(1) "3" 
string(1) "1" 
string(5) "first" 
string(5) "fdsdf" //which means its an array

Comment: No, it's not an array. Each of those 4 items is a string. `string(1)` means string of length 1. `"first"` is a string of 5 character length and therefore it shows `string(5)`.